# How to add Hyperlink dynamically to GridView Row in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, hyperlink

I have a `GirdView` populated with text from code behind, I want to have a row contains a text and another row contains a `HyperLink` .

I use the following code :

```
  Dim dtFull As New DataTable()
            ' Create four typed columns in the DataTable.
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Self Assessment", GetType(Object))
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Staff Development", GetType(Object))
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Mid Meeting", GetType(Object))
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Objectives Rating", GetType(Object))
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Overall Rating", GetType(Object))
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Second Supervisor Approval", GetType(Object))
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Staff Sign Off", GetType(Object))
        dtFull.Columns.Add("Total", GetType(Object))

        dtFull.Rows.Add("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")
        gvGeneralStatistics.DataSource = dtFull
        gvGeneralStatistics.DataBind()
```

How to add HyperLink to the `GridView` row :

Comment: "another row" or "another column" to contain hyperlink? Couldn't you do it in the markup?

Comment: could you be a little more elaborate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to have a TemplateField in your GridView.
and add the hyperlink inside the template field.
you set the hyperlinks values manually from the GridView Columns, or from the code behind in even Row Data Bound!

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use TemplateField coz of its simplicity.
  But if you want to add dynamically you can do it like

**C#:**

```
HyperLinkField hplnk = new HyperLinkField();
hplnk.DataTextField = "YourValue";
hplnk.HeaderText = "yourHeaderTextValue";
gvGeneralStatistics.Columns.Add(hplnk);
```

**Vb.net:**

```
Dim hplnk As New HyperLinkField()
hplnk.DataTextField = "YourValue"
hplnk.HeaderText = "yourHeaderTextValue"
gvGeneralStatistics.Columns.Add(hplnk);
```